# Calibrating a touch screen monitor

Tags: linux-mint, touchscreen

A friend of mine got me a EloTouchSystems 2216 AccuTouch USB TouchMoitor, if was apart of a POS system they were replacing, and I am trying to calibrate it on Linux Mint. I have downloaded the xinput_calibrater app and ran it. Here the output from the program:

```
Calibrating standard Xorg driver "EloTouchSystems,Inc Elo TouchSystems 2216 AccuTouch® USB Touchmonitor Interface"
current calibration values: min_x=0, max_x=65535 and min_y=0, max_y=65535
If these values are estimated wrong, either supply it manually with the --precalib option, or run the 'get_precalib.sh' script to automatically get it (through HAL).
--> Making the calibration permanent <--
copy the snippet below into '/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/99-calibration.conf' (/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/ in some distro's)
Section "InputClass"
    Identifier  "calibration"
    MatchProduct    "EloTouchSystems,Inc Elo TouchSystems 2216 AccuTouch® USB Touchmonitor Interface"
    Option  "MinX"  "5504"
    Option  "MaxX"  "59519"
    Option  "MinY"  "57834"
    Option  "MaxY"  "6123"
    Option  "SwapXY"    "0" # unless it was already set to 1
    Option  "InvertX"   "0"  # unless it was already set
    Option  "InvertY"   "0"  # unless it was already set
EndSection
```

I copied the the snippet as directed to the 99-calibration.conf file, and restarted my computer and nothing happened.

I have tried changing the "InvertX" and "InvertY" values to 1 (changing only one at a time) and rebooting after each time with not success. I am at a lose as to what to do. Can someone offer any suggestions, Please.

P.S. The monitor was manufactured by Fujitsu, and I am using the most current version of Linux Mint.

Additional Information: After posting the question, I realized I did not mention what the touch screen was doing. When I touch the screen and move my finger up and down on the screen, the cursor moves in the opposite direction.

Comment: This is a programming forum. I think you should ask in https://superuser.com/ or maybe https://unix.stackexchange.com.

Comment: My apologizes, I will ask there, thank you